# Array Manipulation in TCL and group them

Tags: tcl

I have two arrays

```
id_array   :{2 1 1 2 3 1 2}
type_array :{apple apple orange orange pineapple pineapple pineapple}
```

I want to process the above arrays and based on the ids and type I want to group following as  follows:

apple 2
apple 1
orange 1 2
pineapple 3
pineapple 1 2

Comment: Note that Tcl uses different terminology: a numerically-indexed array is called a "**list**"; an arbitrary string-indexed array, a hash map, is called an "**array**".

Comment: I see you asked the same question phrased differently (http://stackoverflow.com/q/14241911/7552) -- please explain the algorithm to group items. Why are the oranges grouped but the apples are not?

Comment: oranges are grouped because they are in ascending order for ids and apples are not grouped because they are in descending order. Also for pineapple {3. pineapple} is not grouped, but the last part {{1, pineapple},{2, pineapple}} is grouped . I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very parallel to acheong87's answer, but I'll use a dictionary data structure

```
set types {apple apple orange orange pineapple pineapple pineapple}
set ids {2 1 1 2 3 1 2}

set groups [dict create]
foreach id $ids type $types {
    dict lappend groups $type [list $id $type]
}
puts $groups
# apple {{2 apple} {1 apple}} orange {{1 orange} {2 orange}} pineapple {{3 pineapple} {1 pineapple} {2 pineapple}}

set out [list]
dict for {type sublist} $groups {lappend out $sublist}
puts out
# {{2 apple} {1 apple}} {{1 orange} {2 orange}} {{3 pineapple} {1 pineapple} {2 pineapple}}
```

---

Update due to explanation of requirements:

```
set ids {2 1 1 2 3 1 2}
set types {apple apple orange orange pineapple pineapple pineapple}
set groups [list]
set current_type ""
set prev_id -1
foreach id $ids type $types {
    if {$type ne $current_type || $id < $prev_id} {
        if {[info exists group]} {lappend groups $group}
        set group [list]
        set current_type $type
    }
    lappend group [list $id $type]
    set prev_id $id
}
lappend groups $group
puts [list $groups]
```

This outputs

```
{{{2 apple}} {{1 apple}} {{1 orange} {2 orange}} {{3 pineapple}} {{1 pineapple} {2 pineapple}}}
```

Note the extra braces compared to what you're asking for. The final list `$groups` is a list of lists. Each element (or "sublist") maintains a consistent structure. We see:

- a list with 1 element containing the list {2 apple},
- a list with 1 element containing the list {1 apple},
- a list with 2 elements containing the list {1 orange} and the list {2 orange},
- a list with 1 element containing the list {3 pineapple}, and
- a list with 2 elements containing the list {1 pineapple} and the list {2 pineapple}.

One way to report with this final list is:

```
foreach sublist $groups {
    foreach pair $sublist {
        lassign $pair id type
        puts "$id -> $type"
    }
}
```

printing

```
2 -> apple
1 -> apple
1 -> orange
2 -> orange
3 -> pineapple
1 -> pineapple
2 -> pineapple
```

---

Answering last request: Given the final list above:

```
set answer [list]
foreach sublist $groups {
    lappend answer [lindex $sublist 0 1]
    foreach pair $sublist {lappend answer [lindex $pair 0]}
}
puts [join $answer]
```

prints

```
apple 2 apple 1 orange 1 2 pineapple 3 pineapple 1 2
```

Comment: i am looking for the following final output                            {{2, apple}, {1, apple}, {{1, orange},{2, orange}}, {3, pineapple}, {{1, pineapple}, {2,pineapple}}  can't get that in your answer

Comment: No, because you didn't explain how to create the groups until I asked. Answer updated.

Comment: I don't understand dictionary data structure. I am looking the final output  {{2, apple}, {1, apple}, {{1, orange},{2, orange}}, {3, pineapple}, {{1, pineapple}, {2,pineapple}} how can I get that

Comment: Thanks Glen. The solution is very close. I will just ask you another favor if we can group the list as follows                                                        apple 2
apple 1
orange 1 2
pineapple 3
pineapple 1 2

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Usually, we like to see users' attempts at solving their own problems, as it helps bring focus to a specific ambiguity or misunderstanding that future visitors may find useful. However, we're also usually willing to help regardless:

Tcl has an interesting form of `foreach` that lets us iterate through multiple lists concurrently.

```
set id_array [list 2 1 1 2 3 1 2]
set type_array [list apple apple orange orange pineapple pineapple pineapple]
foreach id $id_array type $type_array {
    lappend hash($type) [list $id $type]
}
foreach name [array names hash] {
    lappend output $hash($name)
}
puts $output
```

This outputs, for me,

```
{{1 orange} {2 orange}} {{3 pineapple} {1 pineapple} {2 pineapple}} {{2 apple} {1 apple}}
```

Comment: Thanks acheong87. I want to keep the same order as mentioned in my original question. How can I display the output